# How to make a div appear if text gets typed into a form input

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have a form input which, when text gets typed into it, updates a div. This is what I use:

```
$('#CampaignTitle').keyup(function() {
    $('#titleBar').text(this.value);
});
```

That works super except I'd also like the ability to hide the div (I know how to make it start off hidden) when there's no text in the form input.

In otherwords when someone types into the form input a div will appear and the text which is being typed into the input appears in the div. If the user clears the input again then the div dissappears.

Sorry I'm new to JS :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do a test to see if the text box value's length is greater than 0:

```
$('#CampaignTitle').keyup(function() {
    if($(this).val().length > 0)
    {
        $('#titleBar').text($(this).val()).show();
    }
    else
    {
        $('#titleBar').hide();
    }
});
```

The key line here being `if($(this).val().length > 0)`.

Comment: As I understand it the `if` *comparison* is unnecessary; since a length of `0` would return, essentially, a falsey value. Therefore `if ($(this).val()` *should* be sufficient. But I'm a little vague on many of the inherent mysteries of JavaScript and jQuery.

Comment: You're most probably correct, however I wanted to be more verbose as the OP is learning JavaScript. Also, I'm not sure what JS does with strings such as `"0"`. In that case, it's more reliable to use `.length`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```
$('#CampaignTitle').keyup(function() {

    var $titleBar = $('#titleBar');

    if(this.value.length == 0) {
       $titleBar.hide();
    }

    else { 

       if($titleBar.is(":hidden")) { 
          $titleBar.show();
       }

       $titleBar.text(this.value);
    }
});
```

It's a bit verbose and there are ways to make it a little less-verbose, but since you're still learning, I figured that this would give you a general idea of what's going on. The `is(":hidden")` check can be omitted; that would run `show()` on `$titleBar` even if it is already visible.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
$('#CampaignTitle').keyup(function() {
    $('#titleBar').text(this.value).show();
    if (this.value==''){ $('#titleBar').hide() }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#CampaignTitle').keyup(function() {
    if (this.value){
        $('#titleBar').text(this.value).show();
    }
    else {
        $('#titleBar').hide();
    }
});
```